# How does Ember.js schedule its dataflow?

Tags: ember.js

The Ember.js documentation [says](http://emberjs.com/documentation/), under the heading Object Model -> Bindings:

> Note that bindings don't update immediately. Ember waits until all of your application code has finished running before synchronizing changes, so you can change a bound property as many times as you'd like without worrying about the overhead of syncing bindings when values are transient.

How does it do this? In your answer, please indicate the path from a call to set some property to the handling of bindings.

I skimmed ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js. I may have followup questions if the answer refers to setTimeout.

Thank you in advance for considering my question.

Comment: Did the link Luke provided sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Not quite. I got a good answer in IRC, and it has more to do with fundamental JavaScript than Ember.js in particular:   




The setTimeout timer will not start until the current thread of execution returns. In this way, you can enqueue the task of handling bindings without worrying about race conditions.  

That, at least, is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The Ember RunLoop is conceptually similar to the Sproutcore RunLoop, and this post is a good overview on it: http://blog.sproutcore.com/the-run-loop-part-1/